# CodeIgniter and Nginx - Class not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I'v uploaded a CodeIgniter application from my localhost with **Apache** to a server running **Nginx**.

Its works perfectly on my localhost and on other server with Apache.

It's under a subdomain, an domain and other subdomains are running PHP 100%.

This application in CI doesn't start, and PHP is returned without being *compiled*.

This is what I get on /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2013/12/05 14:50:31 [error] 20139#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'M_website' not found in /home/webroot/domain.com/cms/system/core/Loader.php on line 303" while reading upstream, client: 84.91.4.220, server: cms.domain.com, request: "GET /websites HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "cms.domain.com"
```

**Class 'M_website' not found in /home/webroot/domain.com/cms/system/core/Loader.php**

This is my subdomain conf.

```
server
{
    server_name cms.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/cms.domain.access.log;
    root /home/webroot/domain.com/cms;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
    }

    # enforce NO www
    if ($host ~* ^www\.(.*))
    {
        set $host_without_www $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ $scheme://$host_without_www/$1 permanent;
    }

    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/websites/(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # canonicalize codeigniter url end points
    # if your default controller is something other than "welcome" you should change the following
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/websites/(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing "index" from all controllers
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # removes access to "system" folder, also allows a "System.php" controller
    if ($request_uri ~* ^/system)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # unless the request is for a valid file (image, js, css, etc.), send to bootstrap
    if (!-e $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    # catch all
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # use fastcgi for all php files
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to apache .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht
    {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

Comment: "PHP is returned without being compiled" --- uhm, what?

Comment: I see the source code! :( if i remove all CI scripts etc and put a simple <?php echo 'hello'; ?> in a index.php it works...

Comment: How does your subdomain [configuration](http://wiki.nginx.org/Codeigniter) look like on Ngnix?

Comment: tnks user1190992.
question has been updated with it.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem.
CI files were starting with <? and not with <?php
Had to edit /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini and set short_open_tag from Off to ON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the problem?

CI files were starting with

```
<?
```

and not with

```
<?php
```

Solution

Had to edit **/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini** and set **short_open_tag** from Off to **On** and restart php-fpm

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: that's why we are here :)